Why is the value of my custom property column not showing up in File Explorer?
I'm feeling really stupid right now.  I've spent far too long on this and must just be missing something fundamental.  What am I missing?
I'm trying to create a new column for File Explorer on Windows 11.  From what I gathered, this requires the registration of a property description file and a property handler (COM server).  I have next to no experience with COM.  I use C# .NET 8, so I went this route rather than C/C++ (I'm using the CsWin32 library to generate the windows types and pinvoke methods).  I'm just trying to get a "Hello World" type of thing going, so I coded it to populate my new column with the value "Kyle" for every file.  I can add the column in File Explorer, but there is never a value showing up for any file in that column.  I added logging and nothing gets logged.  No errors in event viewer, either.
Here's my property description file (stitched together as a best guess from various sources):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2006/propertydescription" schemaVersion="1.0">
    <propertyDescriptionList publisher="Kyle" product="Custom Properties">
        <propertyDescription name="Kyle.CustomProperty.Kyle" formatID="{4F4F4F4F-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF}" propID="100">
            <description>Always displays the name Kyle.</description>
            <searchInfo inInvertedIndex="false" isColumn="true" />
            <typeInfo type="String" multipleValues="false" isViewable="true" isQueryable="false" />
            <labelInfo label="Kyle" invitationText="My name" />
            <displayInfo alignment="left" />
        </propertyDescription>
    </propertyDescriptionList>
</schema>

I wrote a simple console app to register the property description.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="NativeMethods.json" />
        <None Remove="NativeMethods.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <AdditionalFiles Include="NativeMethods.json" />
        <AdditionalFiles Include="NativeMethods.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.CsWin32" Version="0.3.106">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Windows.Win32;

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: RegisterPropertySchema.exe <register|unregister> <schemaPath>");
            return;
        }

        var action     = args[0];
        var schemaPath = args[1];

        if (!RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) || !OperatingSystem.IsWindowsVersionAtLeast(5, 1, 2600))
        {
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("PSRegisterPropertySchema and PSUnregisterPropertySchema are only supported on Windows.");
        }

        switch (action.ToLower())
        {
            case "register":
                RegisterPropertySchema(schemaPath);
                break;
            case "unregister":
                UnregisterPropertySchema(schemaPath);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid action. Use 'register' or 'unregister'.");
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void RegisterPropertySchema(string schemaPath)
    {
        if (!RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) || !OperatingSystem.IsWindowsVersionAtLeast(5, 1, 2600))
        {
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("PSRegisterPropertySchema and PSUnregisterPropertySchema are only supported on Windows.");
        }

        var result = PInvoke.PSRegisterPropertySchema(schemaPath);

        if (result == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Property schema registered successfully.");
        }
        else if (result == 0x000401A0)  // INPLACE_S_TRUNCATED
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Property schema PARTIALLY registered. INPLACE_S_TRUNCATED");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to register property schema. HRESULT: {result:X}");
        }
    }

    private static void UnregisterPropertySchema(string schemaPath)
    {
        if (!RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) || !OperatingSystem.IsWindowsVersionAtLeast(5, 1, 2600))
        {
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("PSRegisterPropertySchema and PSUnregisterPropertySchema are only supported on Windows.");
        }

        var result = PInvoke.PSUnregisterPropertySchema(schemaPath);

        if (result == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Property schema unregistered successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to unregister property schema. HRESULT: {result:X}");
        }
    }
}

And register it like this:
.\RegisterPropertySchema.exe register "C:\Program Files\Kyle\CustomProperty\CustomPropertyKyle.propdesc"
This adds the following to the registry:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertySchema\0003]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Kyle\\CustomProperty\\CustomPropertyKyle.propdesc"
"SchemaId"="{D84D0B56-EAB4-4E60-A125-DD699A684B3C}"
"URI"="custompropertykyle.propdesc"
"CompactURI"="66a088697b1669173504a8c3d90b3614e147d922d8f298de8116bbcd74e5c6b4"

This is my property handler:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
        <EnableRegFreeCom>true</EnableRegFreeCom>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="NativeMethods.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <AdditionalFiles Include="NativeMethods.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.CsWin32" Version="0.3.106">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Windows.Win32.System.Com.StructuredStorage;
using Windows.Win32.System.Variant;
using Windows.Win32.UI.Shell.PropertiesSystem;

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890AB")]
public unsafe class CustomPropertyHandler : IPropertyStore
{
    private static string LogFilePath { get; } = """C:\abc\CustomPropertyHandler.txt""";

    private static PROPERTYKEY PropertyKeyTitle { get; } = new()
                                                           {
                                                               fmtid = new ("4F4F4F4F-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF")
                                                             , pid   = 100
                                                           };

    public void GetCount(out uint propertyCount)
    {
        try
        {
            Log(nameof(GetCount), "START");
            propertyCount = 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(nameof(GetCount), $"   EXCEPTION: {ex.Message}");
            propertyCount = 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log(nameof(GetCount), "   END");
        }
    }

    public void GetAt(uint propertyIndex, PROPERTYKEY* key)
    {
        try
        {
            Log(nameof(GetAt), $"START  propertyIndex: {propertyIndex}");

            ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfNotEqual<uint>(propertyIndex, 0);

            *key = PropertyKeyTitle;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(nameof(GetAt), $"   EXCEPTION: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log(nameof(GetAt), "   END");
        }
    }

    public void GetValue(PROPERTYKEY* key, out PROPVARIANT pv)
    {
        try
        {
            Log(nameof(GetValue), $"START  key: fmtid={key->fmtid} pid={key->pid}");

            pv = new ();

            if (key->fmtid == PropertyKeyTitle.fmtid && key->pid == PropertyKeyTitle.pid)
            {
                Log(nameof(GetValue), "   MATCH");

                pv.Anonymous.Anonymous.vt                = VARENUM.VT_LPWSTR;
                pv.Anonymous.Anonymous.Anonymous.pwszVal = (char*)Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni("Kyle");
            }
            else
            {
                Log(nameof(GetValue), "   NO MATCH");

                pv.Anonymous.Anonymous.vt = VARENUM.VT_EMPTY;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(nameof(GetValue), $"   EXCEPTION: {ex.Message}");
            pv = new();
        }

        Log(nameof(GetValue), "   END");
    }

    public void SetValue(PROPERTYKEY* key, in PROPVARIANT propvar) => Log(nameof(SetValue), $"START  key: {key->fmtid} {key->pid}    propvar: vt={propvar.Anonymous.Anonymous.vt} pwszVal={propvar.Anonymous.Anonymous.Anonymous.pwszVal}");

    public void Commit() => Log(nameof(Commit),  "START");

    private static void Log(string method, string message)
    {
        using var writer = new StreamWriter(LogFilePath, append: true);

        writer.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.sss}   {method}  {message}");
    }
}

I register the handler from a PowerShell 7 Administrator prompt like this:
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Kyle\CustomProperty\CustomPropertyKyle.comhost.dll"
This adds the following to the registry:
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890AB}]
@=".CustomPropertyHandler"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890AB}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Kyle\\CustomProperty\\CustomPropertyKyle.comhost.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890AB}\ProgID]
@=".CustomPropertyHandler"


Registration seems ok if you see it in the Shell. You must also implement one of the InitializeWithXX interfaces so you know what item you're working on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/building-property-handlers-property-handlers#initializing-property-handlers-1 Have you checked your constructor is called? Even with missing interfaces, it should. PS: you can remove the regfree mention since you register it (and regfree won't generally work in this shell ext case).

I think I've identified the problem.  I'm wanting to add a column to file explorer that will work on some well-known, already registered file types like JPG, PNG, etc. (not my own).  This used to be supported before Windows 7 with column handlers, but MS removed that functionality.  The "replacement" is property handlers, which must be tied to a file type, but... Windows only supports one property handler per file type.  Two possible work arounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39535914/15679808 (replace and pass through) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66017828/15679808 (Cloud API).  Thoughts?

Indeed column handlers have been removed completely, the only solution I see for that is to wrap the already registered property handler for a given file type. But it's a good recipe for endangering the user's PC :-s (what happens when repairing, upgrading, etc.) The cloud API requires you to register a root folder as a "sync root", so big overkill and doesn't work for the general "any folder" case (the question is answered by a vendor trying to sell his product...). There's also Shell namespace extensions where you control 100% of propertis but same idea, doesn't work for any folder
